# how to uninstall boost without knowing the installation path

Tags: ubuntu, boost, uninstallation

I have installed boost on ubuntu 16.04 using [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

However, when I search the /usr/local, there is no boost and no libraries of it is installed in /usr/local/lib. 
I searched through the file browser and I found in /usr/share. I don't know why.

I wanna uninstall it and remove all related files and use another method to install it. How can I remove it without giving its installation path, library and include files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for the `boost` include directory on your system with

```
find / -type d -name boost 2>/dev/null
```

Remove this directory entirely. Then,

```
find / -type f -name 'libboost*' 2>/dev/null
```

will print a list of compiled libraries, which you can delete, too. Depending on you installation setup,

```
find / -type d -name boostbook 2>/dev/null
```

will result in a further match, which will be safe to delete. Finally,

```
find / -type f -name b2 -or -name bjam
```

are two executables that ship with boost. You may want to delete those, too. When manually deleting these files and directories, be careful, however: any type in a `sudo rm -rf` command might cause significant damage to your system.

Comment: thanks, I successfully deleted those confusing files :( . What is the better way to install boost? I used [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363177&p=13777992#post13777992], but I am not able to find bootstrap.sh to run it. I searched a lot but there is nothing...

Comment: When working on a linux machine, it's usually best to go with the boost package provided by the package manager (`apt-get`).  This way, you don't have to compile or install anything yourself, and include directories and compiled libs are placed in a default location where every compiler will find them. The package manager will also update boost automatically. Things differ when you depend upon a specific boost version. Then, a manual installation is probably the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, so why the aforementioned link uses ./bootstrap.sh even if it has used apt-get?

Comment: In this link, the user does need a specific version of boost. `apt-get` is used only to remove the boost package such that the desired boost version can manually be installed.

Comment: Thank you for your best and thorough reply. Headers are now located in /usr/include/boost and libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. Should they be located in /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib?

Comment: No, the directories you mentioned should be fine. You can verify by compiling some simple test program using one of the boost headers.

Comment: Something strange has happened. I cannot boot My ubuntu. Maybe i have deleted sth wrong when deleting those files. Do you know anything about it?